# Invalid pointer crash

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, cython

I'm trying to wrap a C library using Cython, and I get a failure attempting to pass a bytes object to a function.

My Python goes as follows:

```
def tou8(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8')

cdef char **alloc_strarr(in_arr, blen=0):
    size = len(in_arr)
    cdef char **out_arr = <char **>calloc(size, sizeof(char *))
    cdef char *tempb
    if out_arr is NULL:
        raise MemoryError()
    fail = 0
    for i in range(0, size):
        b = tou8(in_arr[i])
        if blen:
            out_arr[i] = <char *>calloc(blen, sizeof(char))
            if out_arr[i] is NULL:
                fail = i
                break
            tempb = b
            rc = snprintf(out_arr[i], blen, b'%s', tempb)
            if rc >= blen:
                fail = i
                break
        else:
            out_arr[i] = b
    if fail:
        for i in range(0, fail):
            free(out_arr[i])
        free(out_arr)
        raise MemoryError()
    return out_arr

# this function inside a larger cdef class
def __cinit__(self, fieldc, fieldnames, primkey=''):
    cdef char **cfields = alloc_strarr(fieldnames, blen=FMAXLEN)
    cprimkey = tou8(primkey)
    self._list = so.cq_new_dlist(fieldc, cfields, cprimkey)
    free_all(cfields, len(fieldnames))
    if self._list is NULL:
        raise Exception('Memory or value error creating DataList')
```

I try to execute this by creating a new instance of the class.

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Dec 27 2014, 13:16:08) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mymodule
>>> dl = mymodule.MyClass(1, ['test'])
*** Error in `python3': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fa4b6a17320 ***
Aborted
```

What's going wrong in my initialization process?

Comment: A complete, reproducible answer would be helpful.  You might also consider adding some print statements to see where exactly it goes bad.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `out_arr[i] = b` the pointer stored in `out_arr[i]` is pointing to memory heald by `b` and only valid as long as the object pointed to by `b` is not garbage collected (e.g. during the next iteration).